# Finding Hamming distance between 2 threshold image with python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hamming-distance, iris-recognition

I'm doing iris recognition and I have 2 threshold images of iris.
How can I do hamming distance between the 2 images with Python ?
thx

[image]

Here you have the original image before polar transform:

[image]

and the code:

```
img_crop1 = cv.imread('crop_1.png')
    polar_img = cv.warpPolar(
        img_crop1, (256, 1024), (self.iris_1[0], self.iris_1[1]), self.iris_1[2] * 2, cv.WARP_POLAR_LINEAR)
    # Rotate it sideways to be more visually pleasing
    polar_img = cv.rotate(polar_img, cv.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    # crop image
    polar_img = polar_img[int(polar_img.shape[0] / 2)
                          : polar_img.shape[0], 0: polar_img.shape[1]]
    polar_img = cv.cvtColor(polar_img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    _, threshold = cv.threshold(polar_img, 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv.imwrite("foreground.png", threshold)
```

Comment: And can you explain how the images are represented?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it's the threshold of a polar image with WARP_POLAR_LINEAR method.

Comment: that image is broken. the polar warp was given a wrong iris center. a proper warp would result in straight lines (circles), not this bump. -- you should also post *source* data instead of filtered digestive products, and multiple images since you are dealing with *comparison*.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have this bump because I deleted the pupil, I will add the original image and my code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you have 2 thresholded images `imageTH_1` and `imageTH_2` that is we have binary images, `0` & `1` representing black & white respectively.

First [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) you images so they are now 1D arrays,

```
import numpy as np

flat_1 = imageTH_1.flatten()
flat_2 = imageTH_2.flatten()
```

Now you can use [Scipy's Hamming distance calculator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html)

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

ham_dist = distance.hamming(flat_1, flat_2)
```

Comment: Hamming distance seems not to be very precise because 2 similar images have 0, 2 very different images have 30 - 50 and two similar images but different have 20- 35.

Comment: Yes, using Hamming distance for images is very limited in my experience. You might want to consider using [Structural Similarity Index](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/)

Comment: I did it with open cv akaze :)

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:
sum(im1 xor im2)

Comment: I kind of suspect OPs wants to know how to do it using images as represented by the opencv library.

Comment: that's not the best solution because I try to do it with Open CV after the normalisation if my two images I got the following result but now I need to check the hamming distance to know if iris are the same or not.

Comment: Maybe it's   "cv::sum(cv::bitwise_xor(im1,im2))" assuming thresholding produces pixel values of 0 and 1.

Comment: @MarkLavin pixels are 0 or 255
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]
 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [255 255 255]
  ...
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]
 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]
 ...
 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
 
  ...
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]]

Comment: "cv::sum( cv::bitwise_xor(im1, im2) / 255 )"

Comment: @MarkLavin got npm array of [56. 56. 56.]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand; what's "npm"?

Comment: @MarkLavin numpy array

Comment: "npm" is some node.js thing. numpy is abbreviated "np".